# Edit .htaccess file to allow .php execution

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

The following entry in my .htaccess file was preventing a Wordpress .php script from executing and causing errors on my website.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:php)$">
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I have removed the entry and it resolved the problem.  However, I don;t know if this has then left my website at risk.  How would be the best way to allow a certain file to run (taxonomy-redirect.php) without causing any undue risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing this block altogether will allow execution of any `.php` file and that might cause security issues.

**You should allow just `taxonomy-redirect.php` while still disallowing other `.php` files using a negative lookbehind regex like this**:

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!taxonomy-redirect)\.(?i:php)$">
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```